# Track Google Analytics and then redirect..?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I've got a WordPress plugin that I'm going to be running some ad campaigns for and I'd like to send the users directly to the [plugin directory page](http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/), but I need to log the traffic so it shows up in my Google Analytics.

I'm trying to build a little "middle man" script I can use for this, but I'm struggling to find a working solution out of all the potential ones I'm finding.

I'm using the new Analytics tracking code:

```
<script>
  (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
  (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
  m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
  })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

  ga('create', 'UA-2xxxx3-1', 'angelleye.com');
  ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
```

From what I've read I need to add a javascript redirect into this, but delay it for 1 or 2 seconds so the Analytics will have time to track before the redirect happens.  I'm not good enough with javascript to get this done, I guess.

Any info would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1136920?hl=en-GB would be a good place to start.

Comment: That seems to talking about clickable outbound links.  I just want the page to get hit, log the Analytics, and immediately redirect so the user never sees the actual page, but instead the first thing they'd see is the page that my page redirects to.

Comment: Maybe instead of onclick I would use onload..??

Comment: Maybe instead of building an extra man in the middle page, link directly to the plugin directory page and use the code Google provide. That way your link continues to work even if JS is off/blocked/broken/whatever :)

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you're saying.  I can't embed any code on the WordPress directory page.  That's the problem.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding then. Are you sending users *to* the wordpress plugin page, or tracking visits *from* it? Do you control the site they're going to/from?

Comment: I want the landing page of the campaign to be the WordPress directory page, which I don't control.  I want to be able to log the traffic that the campaign is sending it, though, in Analytics.  I'm trying to set the actual landing of the campaign to a page on my site so that I can track it with Analytics, but then immediately redirect to the WP directory page so that is the first thing people see when they click the campaign link.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a Custom page on your website, which has the Analytics Code + Redirect Code. You may use a JavaScript redirect code like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function()
        {
        alert("Hello")
        //location.href="http://wordpress.org/plugins/paypal-for-woocommerce/"
    },3000);
</script>
```

Just comment the Alert and Uncomment the redirect...

Answer (score 0):

I was in the exact same situation and I used Google Tag Manager to create a tag that fires when the link to the WP directory is clicked. I found multiple sets of instructions, so took some fiddling to finally get it working, but this is what I have. There are 3 components:

1. A "Link Click Listener" tag that has an "All pages" firing rule.
2. A UGA (Universal Google Analytics) LinkOut tag with one firing rule:

{{event}} = gtm.linkClick

{{element url}} contains wordpress.org/plugins/yourpluginnamehere

1. A general UGA tag that fires on all pages

Good luck!